# Fatal error - but it works - will not activate

Tags: mysql, wordpress, plugins, fatal-error

Been building a custom plugin for Wordpress which works but doesn't.

When I activate the plugin with the following code it:

1. creates the table
2. and inserts the data (although 3 times?).

Then get "Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error."

- No debug log gets created
- There are no errors in the console.
- the form works and submits

This is the create table function:

```
    function db1_install() {
        global $wpdb;
        global $db_version1;
        global $table_name;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'myCategories';   
        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();    
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
            id mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
            item varchar(20) NOT NULL,
            item_cat varchar(20) NOT NULL
            ) $charset_collate;";
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
        add_option( 'db_version1', $db_version1 );    
    } 
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'db1_install' );
```

And this is the Data insert function:

```
`enter code here`function add_categories(){

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'myCategories';
    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $table_name (id,item,item_cat)
    values (1,'item1','cat1'), (2,'item2','cat1'), (2,'item3','cat4')");
    die();
    return true;
    }
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'add_categories');
```

anyone?

Comment: Two potential issues I see in your code are, 1) The `die();` in your `add_categories()` function might be messing with WordPress' ability to discern if the plugin was activated successfully. 2) `global $table_name;`. You should not put your table in the global namespace as it could conflict with other plugins.

Comment: Hey Lucas - You are totally correct. Thanks for the comment. You helped me immensely and I removed the table from the global. Thanks again for your insight.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked.

Comment: P.S. I'm going to move my comment to be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two potential issues I see in your code are,

1. The `die();` in your `add_categories()` function might be messing with WordPress' ability to discern if the plugin was activated successfully.
2. Your use of `global $table_name;`. You should not put your table in the global namespace as it could conflict with other plugins.

Comment: Thanks, Lucas - the die(); was the issue. I also change the table_name variable and now it all works.